# How to send a HTTP "Bad Request" Response

Tags: http, http-headers

I am writing a C program which needs to send back a HTTP Bad Response.
This is what I write to socket.

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
\r\n
```

My question is why the broswer still spinning (like appear it is still loading something?
Am I missing header in the Http response? OR I miss something else?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you monitor the headers you are sending (firefox live http headers comes to mind) and tell us what is happening ?
P.S. are you sure you are also flushing and closing everything?

Comment: If it's IE (at least an old version of IE) you need to send it 512 bytes before it will acknowledge a response.  Just send it some junk in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Connection: close
```

does not close connection immediately - it just indicates, that connection will not be reused after current request - it is opposite of `Connection: keep-alive`. Try to include `Content-Length: 0` to indicate that there is no content at all.

Or, just close your socket.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually closing the connection afterwards?